# Recovering Wifi Password Using Python

Tags: python-2.7, passwords, wifi

I just bought a new Macbook Pro, but I forgot to write down my own wifi password. I tried contacting my ISPs (or whatever you call them) but no one responded. I don't think I will ever get an answer from them.

Using Python 2.7.9, is a program able to hack into my own wifi and retrieve the password?

Comment: Just reset your router to factory settings. There should be a little button somewhere on your router (usually on the bottom).

Answer (score 0):

The password for the wifi will be stored in the keychain => /Applications/Utilities/
It will be in either the Login keychain or System keychain, just double click the keychain entry with the wifi name and tick show password, once you have entered your password it should show you the password used to connect to the network.

Comment: No need to complicate with a script.

Comment: Then login into the router and view it or reset it. No need to hack your own router.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your router via ethernet. You should then be able to set the wifi password to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

If the password is connected to your device. Then try this script  But I Dont prefer using script  for such easy tasks.
Try this:

```
brew install wifi-password
```

Get more details on this page
https://github.com/rauchg/wifi-password